# Can' reopen drop-menu closed by jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I don't understand why if I close a drop-menu by jQuery, then I can't reopen it by clicking on the button.

The code of the drop-menu:

```
                   <div class="btn-group">
                   <button type="button" id="BtPeriod" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm brd-rad-0 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                       <i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i><span class="pad-20">15 last days</span><span class="caret"></span>
                   </button>
                   <div class="dropdown-menu pull-right pad-20 bor-g-1" style="width:420px;">
                       <div class="fnt-1-5 pad-b-20 brd-rad-6"><i class="fa fa-area-chart pad-r-20"></i>Timelaps of Lines Charts</div>
                       <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-xs-6"><button type="button" id="BtLast15days" class="btn btn-grey brd-rad-0 btn-block">15 last days</button></div>
                           <div class="col-xs-6"><button type="button" id="BtCurrentMonth" class="btn btn-grey brd-rad-0 btn-block">The current month</button></div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
```

The jQuery code to close it:

```
    $("#BtCurrentMonth").on("click", function(event) {
if(!$("#BtCurrentMonth").hasClass("disabled")) {
    if(isMobile.any() == null) parent.NProgress.start() ;
    $("#BtPeriod").html("<i class='fa fa-area-chart'></i><span class='pad-20'>The current month</span><i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg'></i>") ;
    //$(".dropdown-menu").hide() ;
    //$("#BtPeriod").prop("disabled", true) ;
    //$(".dropdown-menu").slideUp("fast") ;
    $("#IfAccountsChart").attr("src", "http://localhost/dev.sublime-art.com/sublime-admin/pages/adminhome/iframes/if_accounts_charts.php?period=onemonth") ;
}
});
```

If I uncomment one of these 3 ways of closing the dropdown-menu, I find myself with a dropdown-menu I can't reopen.

Any idea why ?
Thanks :)

**Edit**

```
$(".btn-group").removeClass("open");
```

works like a charm :)

Comment: Do you have code that opens it?

Comment: No I don't have. Didn't think I need it as it opens on the first click on #BtPeriod.

Comment: So just so I understand the issue completely, you click the button, it opens (where is this code?), you click the button again, it closes, and then you click the button a third time and it doesn't open?

Comment: Yes the opening works thanks to bootstrap dropdow-menu default behaviour, like in this example: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h. But when adding some jQuery, the default behaviour doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need any close code at all. Bootstrap seems to be handling it for you.

Comment: $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');  or $('.btn-group').removeClass('open');

Comment: If I add some jQuery to close it hide(), prop(, slideUp(, then it does not open anymore. The default bootsrtrap behaviour is not anymore.

Comment: Yes, thanks @gaetanoM. $(".btn-group").removeClass("open"); works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is adding and removing the "open" class on your dropdown, the hide/show capability is done in css. So your code is hiding the menu in a way that the class can't show the menu.

It doesn't look like you need any code to close it as Bootstrap handles that for you, but if you must, try:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").removeClass("open");
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: On `$(".btn-group").removeClass("open");` works like a charm :)